# C# Cannot dispatch an event because of implicit threading

Tags: c#, event-handling, thread-safety

Im trying to write a class to make a simple RFID reader, in this case it's COM, I want to dispatch a event when a different RFID was red, but I get an error due to Threading, Im not using threads directly, but SerialPort does.

```
class LectorCOM
{
    SerialPort puerto;
    public event EventHandler OnLectura;

    public LectorCOM()
    {
        puerto = new SerialPort();
        ...
        puerto.DataReceived += delegate {
             this.OnLectura(this,EventArgs.Empty);
        }; 
    }
 }
```

but it throws the following error:

System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233079
  Message=Operación no válida a través de subprocesos: Se tuvo acceso al control 'textBox2' desde un subproceso distinto a aquel en que lo creó.
  Source=System.Windows.Forms

I found solutions that involve Thread class, but Im not using it, I want this class to be generic for use in different aplications, so I cannot reference directly to Form1 from this class.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I partially solved it by adding a Control property and I pass the form to the constructor, but I don't like this workaround because maybe the users of my class wont use it from a Form but a simple class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `DataReceived` thread is raised on a system-managed IO completion port thread.
That thread cannot access the UI.

To fix this, you can call the `Invoke()` method on any control in your UI layer and pass a delegate that does the UI work.

You can also capture the `SynchronizationContext` from the UI thread in your non-UI class (in a field in the constructor), then call its `Post()` method to raise the entire event on the UI thread.

Comment: Invoke is not part of my non-ui class, and I don't know how to get the reference to the base thread, also to dispatch the event I need to call this.OnLectura(this,EventArgs.Empty), which is not on hte ui class

Comment: I couldnt use Invoke() because I had no referenche to the main thread, it worked for a while passing the UI as reference but I didn't like that solution, so I got the current SyncronizationContext in the constructor line (it runs in the main thread but the code is located in the second class, that's the trick)